# Multiple Input Python

Tags: python

I need to write a program in which user is asked:
to select 1 (and only 1) team amongst 3 teams and
to select 1 or several products amongst a longer product list.

My code works fine with 1 product only.

Any hint?
(I found this [useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) related, but not really documented on multiple selection)

Here is my program (Python 3.7)

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

# User select 1 team, uppercase
teams = {'OTEAM', 'ZTEAM', 'DREAMTEAM'}
prompts = chain(["Enter 1 team: "], repeat("No such team? Try again: "))
replies = map(input, prompts)
valid_response = next(filter(teams.__contains__, replies))
# Show team selected
print(f"you want to configure {valid_response}")

# User select 1 or several product, 
products = {'Aprod', 'Bprod', 'Cprod'}
prompts_prod = chain(["Enter product(s): "], repeat("No such product, try again: "))
replies_prod = map(input, prompts_prod)
valid_response_prod = next(filter(products.__contains__, replies_prod))
print(f"---Result --- \nin {valid_response} you want to configure \n{valid_response_prod}")
```

Comment: How should the multiple products be entered? One per line until e. g. an empty line is entered or all on one line separated by spaces, commas, both, something else?

Comment: That's quite an obfuscated approach for getting user input and checking it against a list..

Comment: If you were to simply use a loop you could loop while the user continues to provide valid input

Comment: User will normally include its produt list using a space separated format. I can not really use a loop as product list may contain up to 20 different products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the users provide a product list in a space-separated format then change your code to accept that, split it into a set and use set operations to find the products they have entered that are valid, and those that are invalid.

```
products = {'Aprod', 'Bprod', 'Cprod'}

requested_products = set(input("Enter Space Separated Product List").split())
selected_products = requested_products.intersection(products)
invalid_products = requested_products-selected_products

#Do something with invalid products e.g.
print(f'Accepted products {",".join([p for p in selected_products])}')
print(f'Invalid products {",".join([p for p in invalid_products])}')

Up to you at that point whether you error, loop until there are non invalid, etc.
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I need. Thank you for the example.

Comment: @jm_her, make sure to accept this answer if it met your needs